# PineScript Why the request.securiry() work on D1 and doesnt on lower TF?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

Im try to get daily ATR for last 5 days. Code work perfect on D1 but take another result on lower timeframes. Why? Seems like [dh, dl] on lower TF contains only current day info

```
[dh,dl] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high,low], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
if barstate.isrealtime
    log.info("==============")
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[0] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[1] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[2] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[3] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[4] ))
```

If run this code on 1D, result is (expected):

```
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.0839
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.08643
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.08424
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.0868
```

But if run it on 5 (5 min), than:

```
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
```

Comment: upd. i add result examples